# How to insert access token into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, api, instagram

I am trying to insert the Instagram access token into the Mysql database. please remember that this is just for practice purposes.

I have a DB **structure** like this for storing the Instagram access token:
[image: here]

So, what I trying to do is, insert the Instagram **access token** with **username** in the **DB** which I did successfully. Now, if each access token represents individual user then I want is:

if the user already exists in the database then grab the access token from the DB and pass it to `GetUserProfileInfo()` and if the user does not exist in DB(NEW USER) then Insert the access token in Database.

Here is my bad practice:p

```
$insta_data = $instagram_ob->GetAccessToken(INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID, INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI, INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET, $_GET['code']);

$exist = new existance();
$user_exist = $exist-> exist($insta_data['user']['id']);

if($user_exist == 0) //user not exist {
    $instagram_ob->insertoken($insta_data['access_token'], $insta_data['user']['username']); //calling function to insert access token into db

}else {
    $data = $exist-> fetch($insta_data['user']['id']); // fetch user details from db

    if($data) {
        // Get user insta information
        $user_info = $instagram_ob->GetUserProfileInfo($data['access_token']);
        echo 'db access token';
    } else {
        // Get user insta information
        $user_info = $instagram_ob->GetUserProfileInfo($insta_data['access_token']);
        echo 'api access token';
    }
}
```

`$user_exist` is always 0 I don't know why:/

**fetch class**

```
class existance
{
    public function exist($insta_id)
    {
        $Dbobj = new DbConnection();  
        $query = mysqli_query($Dbobj->getdbconnect(), "SELECT id FROM access WHERE uid='.$insta_id.'");
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        return $total;
    }

    public function fetch($insta_id)
    {
        $Dbobj = new DbConnection(); 
        $query = mysqli_query($Dbobj->getdbconnect(), "SELECT * FROM access WHERE uid='.$insta_id.'");
        $fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        return $fetch_data;
    }
}
```

I am really unsure whether this is a good practice or not but giving my best but also looking for some alternatives as well it would be my pleasure if someone guides me in this:)

Comment: Why `VARCHAR(222)`? A normal default is `VARCHAR(255)`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: just typed by randomly

Comment: Try and be more deliberate in your database design. When you get sloppy those little things can catch up and frustrate you later.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Nops never heard of that:/

Comment: You're already half-way to building one, so before you invest several years of your life in re-inventing the wheel, as it's an increasingly tricky task as the complexity builds, I'd suggest having a look at the pre-existing ones to save yourself the trouble. Most of these can be extended as necessary to accommodate any unusual use-cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the `uid` anywhere in the database.

Do you mean to write `access_token`

`$query = mysqli_query($Dbobj->getdbconnect(), "SELECT id FROM access WHERE access_token='.$insta_id.'");` instead?